# How do I extend my PATH environment variable?

Tags: windows, path, environment-variables

Being a power user, my %PATH% variable just isn't long enough to install everything I want to install.

Is there any way I can extend the effective length of the variable, or otherwise get more paths available?

I'd prefer to use system variables, rather than user variables.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SUBST` for long paths, and assign a drive letter. Add that to the path, and you've just increased your variable length.

`SUBST x: "A\very\long\path\here"`

Where `x:` is an unused driver letter. Then in your `PATH` variable, replace `"A\very\long\path\here"` with `x:`